# FTP backup software

Tags: windows, backup, ftp

Does anyone know any good software to back file from FTP? I can only find some that backs up to FTP, not from.

I want to daily backup my server files.

A plus would be if the software had automatic back up and would back it up into a ZIP with correct named dates and everything.

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I can recommend [Cobian Backup](http://www.cobiansoft.com/cobianbackup.htm) for this purpose. It's a general purpose backup software that can backup from/to a range of devices and protocols, including FTP, with the added capability of packing the backup into a ZIP file with a naming convention you chose. Its main features are:

- Backup to/from lone files, whole folders (including network shares) and FTP servers.
- Can schedule daily/weekly/monthly/yearly/periodic intervals for automatic backups, or manually triggered.
- Can do a plain file copy from source to target or pack the result into a .zip or .7z file, optionally with compression and password-protected encryption.
- Backup file names can be configured, being the date of the backup by default.
- Has full/differential/incremental backups, automatically deleting older copies and ciclying newer ones.
- Can run custom commands as pre-backup and post-backup events.
- Can use VSS service to backup locked files (although probably doesn't works for FTP sources)

On the bad side, the program lacks mainteinance (last version was released a few years ago). It's completely free but not open source (it used to be, and an older repository is still out there).

Comment: I tried it but all the times I did, it got stuck at 0% downloading.

Answer (score 0):

From globalscape.com

> Easily create and schedule labor- and time-saving script transfers
>   with minimal overhead using the Transfer Engine from within CuteFTP or
>   with any COM-enabled scripting or programming language. Create scripts
>   to regularly backup or synchronize your sites, and monitor local
>   folders for changes; or just drag and drop files for fast and easy
>   movement—up to 100 concurrent transfers.

Note that it's a paid software. You can backup your files and schedule them from menu: Tools > Folder Tools > Backup Local to Remote

[CuteFTP web page](https://www.globalscape.com/cuteftp)

[image: screenshot]